# How to specify clicking a class when there are multiple with the same class name. (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<li class="mod-tile">
<ul class="gallery-hidden gallery">
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/1982/1982-1579465585-271404739.png" data-sub-html="Stracker's Loader " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/1982/1982-1579465585-271404739.png" />
</ul>
<div data-mod-id="1982" data-game-id="2531" class="mod-tile-left ">
<div class="expandtile">
<ul class="btnexpand btnoverlay inline-flex">
<div class="padding"></div>
<svg title="" class="icon-plus"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-plus"></use></svg> <li>
<ul>
<li><a class="mod-view" href="index.html">View mod page</a></li>
<li><a class="mod-gallery" href="index.html">View image gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="mod-image" href="index.html">
<figure class="image_figure">
<img class="back" src="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg" width="600" height="338">
<div class="fore_div_mods">
<img class="fore" onerror="imgError(this,'https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg')" loading="lazy" src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/1982/1982-1579465585-271404739.png" alt="Stracker's Loader" title="Stracker's Loader">
</div>
</figure>
</a>
<div class="tile-desc motm-tile">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">Stracker's Loader</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Utilities</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2020-01-19 20:26"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
19 Jan 2020 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 04 Dec 2020</div>
<div class="realauthor"><span class="label">Author: </span> Stracker</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Uploader: </span> <a href="index.html">Stracker</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
Restores full nativePC functionality. </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tile-data">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li class="sizecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-filesize"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-filesize"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">
703KB </span>
</li>
<li class="endorsecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-endorse"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-endorse"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">26.0k</span>
</li>
<li class="downloadcount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-downloads"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-downloads"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label"> -- </span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mod-tile-right">
<div class="tile-desc">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">Stracker's Loader</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Utilities</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2020-01-19 20:26"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
19 Jan 2020 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 04 Dec 2020</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Author: </span><a href="index.html">Stracker</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
Restores full nativePC functionality. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="mod-tile">
<ul class="gallery-hidden gallery">
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/112/112-1579010242-745113274.png" data-sub-html="Souvenir's Light Pillar " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/112/112-1579010242-745113274.png" />
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/112/112-1579010135-1239485031.png" data-sub-html="Souvenir's Light Pillar " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/112/112-1579010135-1239485031.png" />
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/112/112-1579010181-399571475.png" data-sub-html="Souvenir's Light Pillar " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/112/112-1579010181-399571475.png" />
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/112/112-1579259504-344088346.png" data-sub-html="Souvenir's Light Pillar " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/112/112-1579259504-344088346.png" />
</ul>
<div data-mod-id="112" data-game-id="2531" class="mod-tile-left ">
<div class="expandtile">
<ul class="btnexpand btnoverlay inline-flex">
<div class="padding"></div>
<svg title="" class="icon-plus"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-plus"></use></svg> <li>
<ul>
<li><a class="mod-view" href="index.html">View mod page</a></li>
<li><a class="mod-gallery" href="index.html">View image gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="mod-image" href="index.html">
<figure class="image_figure">
<img class="back" src="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg" width="600" height="338">
<div class="fore_div_mods">
<img class="fore" onerror="imgError(this,'https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg')" loading="lazy" src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/112/112-1579010242-745113274.png" alt="Souvenir's Light Pillar" title="Souvenir's Light Pillar">
</div>
</figure>
</a>
<div class="tile-desc motm-tile">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">Souvenir's Light Pillar</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Visuals and Graphics</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2018-09-03 19:58"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
03 Sep 2018 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 17 Jan 2020</div>
<div class="realauthor"><span class="label">Author: </span> 2hh8899</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Uploader: </span> <a href="index.html">2hh8899</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
It lights up the souvenirs for making them easier to find.유실물을 찾기 쉽게 하기 위해 빛기둥을 박아넣었습니다. </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tile-data">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li class="sizecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-filesize"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-filesize"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">
59KB </span>
</li>
<li class="endorsecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-endorse"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-endorse"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">22.7k</span>
</li>
<li class="downloadcount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-downloads"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-downloads"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label"> -- </span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mod-tile-right">
<div class="tile-desc">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">Souvenir's Light Pillar</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Visuals and Graphics</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2018-09-03 19:58"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
03 Sep 2018 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 17 Jan 2020</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Author: </span><a href="index.html">2hh8899</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
It lights up the souvenirs for making them easier to find.유실물을 찾기 쉽게 하기 위해 빛기둥을 박아넣었습니다. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="mod-tile">
<ul class="gallery-hidden gallery">
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/43/43-1534824818-145235267.png" data-sub-html="MHW Transmog " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/43/43-1534824818-145235267.png" />
<li class="thumb" data-src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/43/43-1534825195-804021906.png" data-sub-html="MHW Transmog " data-exthumbimage="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/43/43-1534825195-804021906.png" />
</ul>
<div data-mod-id="43" data-game-id="2531" class="mod-tile-left ">
<div class="expandtile">
<ul class="btnexpand btnoverlay inline-flex">
<div class="padding"></div>
<svg title="" class="icon-plus"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-plus"></use></svg> <li>
<ul>
<li><a class="mod-view" href="index.html">View mod page</a></li>
<li><a class="mod-gallery" href="index.html">View image gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="mod-image" href="index.html">
<figure class="image_figure">
<img class="back" src="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg" width="600" height="338">
<div class="fore_div_mods">
<img class="fore" onerror="imgError(this,'https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/default/noimage.svg')" loading="lazy" src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/mods/2531/images/thumbnails/43/43-1534824818-145235267.png" alt="MHW Transmog" title="MHW Transmog">
</div>
</figure>
</a>
<div class="tile-desc motm-tile">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">MHW Transmog</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Utilities</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2018-08-21 05:37"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
21 Aug 2018 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 04 Dec 2020</div>
<div class="realauthor"><span class="label">Author: </span> Approved</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Uploader: </span> <a href="index.html">FineNerds</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
A mod that allows you to hot swap your appearance with any armor of your choice. Visible to other players!As with any mod for games that don't support mods. This is USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tile-data">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li class="sizecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-filesize"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-filesize"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">
260KB </span>
</li>
<li class="endorsecount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-endorse"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-endorse"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label">12.2k</span>
</li>
<li class="downloadcount inline-flex">
<svg title="" class="icon icon-downloads"><use xlink:href="https://www.nexusmods.com/assets/images/icons/icons.svg#icon-downloads"></use></svg> <span class="flex-label"> -- </span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mod-tile-right">
<div class="tile-desc">
<div class="fadeoff"></div>
<div class="tile-content">
<h3><a href="index.html">MHW Transmog</a></h3>
<div class="meta clearfix">
<div class="category">
<a href="index.html">Utilities</a>
</div>
<time class="date" datetime="2018-08-21 05:37"> <span class="label">Uploaded: </span>
21 Aug 2018 </time>
<div class="date"><span class="label">Last Update:</span> 04 Dec 2020</div>
<div class="author"><span class="label">Author: </span><a href="index.html">FineNerds</a></div>
</div>
<p class="desc">
A mod that allows you to hot swap your appearance with any armor of your choice. Visible to other players!As with any mod for games that don't support mods. This is USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

So I want selenium to open the first link from that has the class "**mod-tile**" then it will do a script that I have made, then I want it to open the next link that has the same class "**mod-tile**". Is there any way to specify this? (btw don't mind the description I just copied the first 3 mod tiles that appeared on the website)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of elements with the  find_**elements**_by_class_name() method.
Then iterate through the list of elements.

[UPDATED]
Following should click the fist link (//a) within the "mod-tile" elements

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-tile")
print("mod-title count {}".format(len(elements)))

for element in range(len(elements)):
  elements[element].find_element_by_xpath("//a").click()
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to selenium, how do I iterate through the elements?

Comment: Sample code demonstrate iterating  through the elements. First line get the list of elements with the class name. Then the for loop iterate through the list of elements.

Comment: pasted code into my script and it only opens 1 link and it doesn't seem to run the rest of the code that I have (finding and clicking files -> find and clicking manual download)

Comment: Code is updated to click first link from each  **mod-tile** sections. print statement is added to check the elements with mod-tile. This should be more than one. Else we need to investigate further.

Comment: The updated code doesn't work for me, it sends the tab to nexusmods.com base site not the mods, [pastebin link + github for code at bottom](https://pastebin.com/KQBZBcy7)